# How to setup solr on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, aws-opsworks

Lets assume my domain name as "abc.com" and I want to run solr on this domain like "abc.com:8983/solr".

I have created 1 load balancer, 1 instance and 1 app. also installed solr on the instance and started solr.

But I'm not able to access this link "abc.com:8983/solr".
I'm getting timeout error.

Comment: what are your security group settings?

Comment: I added 8983 port in inbound ec2 group settings. But still its not working.

Comment: I'm also trying this "http://public-dns:8983" but its also not working. I have seen 8983 port is there in ec2 group setting rules.

Comment: Its started working by changing default jetty port from 8983 to 80. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change port number to :80.